# Confusing documentation for UEFI's BootServices->GetMemoryMap()

Tags: c, intel, uefi

I am trying to call the `BootServices->GetMemoryMap()` function, but the function definition and the documentation does not make sense to me. The UEFI spec (v2.6) says that the definition of the function is (page: 207):

```
typedef EFI_STATUS(EFIAPI *EFI_GET_MEMORY_MAP)(IN OUT UINTN *MemoryMapSize, IN OUT EFI_MEMORY_DESCRIPTOR *MemoryMap, OUT UINTN *MapKey, OUT UINTN *DescriptorSize, OUT UINT32 *DescriptorVersion);
```

But the parameters section says:

> *MemoryMap*: A pointer to the buffer in which firmware places the current 
>   memory map.  The map is an array of 
>   EFI_MEMORY_DESCRIPTORs.

If the memory map is an array of `EFI_MEMORY_DESCRIPTOR`s and the parameter is supposed to be a pointer to a buffer, how can the parameter's type be `IN OUT EFI_MEMORY_DESCRIPTOR *MemoryMap`, shouldn't it be `IN OUT EFI_MEMORY_DESCRIPTOR **MemoryMap`?

Comment: It says " A pointer to the buffer in which firmware places the current memory map." An array is a pointer to a buffer arguably. Maybe interpret like this, `A pointer to the buffer (first memory address of the buffer) in which ... ` `**MemoryMap` would be address of yet another address which is the beging of the buffer. So it would be a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: It depends on the author's meaning of the word buffer. In function it would be an address but in common speak it would be the whole area of address making up the buffer. In the later it seems there is no contradiction, thus either there is a mistake or the context reveals it doesn't refer to exact functional definition of buffer.

Comment: @marshalcraft: Thanks, I got it. It seems a little odd they would do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The map is an array of EFI_MEMORY_DESCRIPTORs.

If the map is an array of `EFI_MEMORY_DESCRIPTOR`s then the name of the array decays to a pointer to the first element in that array, i.e to the

```
EFI_MEMORY_DESCRIPTOR *MemoryMap
```

So given the function

```
EFI_STATUS efi_get_memorymap(IN OUT UINTN *MemoryMapSize,
                             IN OUT EFI_MEMORY_DESCRIPTOR *MemoryMap, ...);
```

and a map of descriptors

```
EFI_MEMORY_DESCRIPTOR memory_map[2];
```

you can pass the array this way:

```
status = efi_get_memorymap(size, memory_map, ...);
```

Comment: Then how do I declare a variable to store the array? Right now I am doing it like `EFI_MEMORY_DESCRIPTOR memoryMap;` and calling the function like `systemTableLocal.BootServices->GetMemoryMap(&mapSize, &memoryMap, &mapKey, &descriptiorSize, &descriptiorVersion);`.

Comment: You should pass array by name not an address of name.